# Android:autolink. Не реагирует на некоторые ссылки.

Tags: android, html, java

Здравствуйте!

Беру из `Html` текст и вставляю в `TextView`, у которого установлено свойство `android:autolink="all"` и `android:linksClickable="true"`.

Ссылки, оформленные вот так:

```
<a  href="http://www.site.ru">www.site.ru</a>
```

Прекрасно предлагают перейти по ним.  Ссылки, оформленные:

```
<a href="http://www.site.ru/asd/manual.aspx">на сайте разработчика</a>
```

На нажатия никоим образом не реагирует. В чем подвох?

Comment: android:autoLink="" не принимает значения "true", кстати.

Comment: Прошу прощения, опечатка вышла.

Answer (score 2):

autolink выделяет не HTML теги, а сами ссылки. То есть если вы напишете

> Перейдите на мой сайт mysite.ru

то mysite.ru станет кликабельным. 
Чтобы работали ссылки вида `< a href="http://www.site.ru/asd/manual.aspx" >` на сайте разработчика `< /a>`, надо делать так:

```
TextView textview = findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("< a href="http://www.site.ru/asd/manual.aspx" >на сайте разработчика< /a>"));
```

Comment: Именно так и делаю, ссылки подсвечиваются, но не все работают.